# Select Day, Month and Year Date from DropDownList in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I use this code for populate my own Day, Month and Year Date Selector using three DropDownList in ASP.Net

Now I need set as default value for each DDL the vakue of `DateTime.MinValue`, that is `01/01/0001` , because the value of date to be recorded in the database is not always available :

1. in DDL `ddlday` I need as default value : `01`;
2. in DDL `ddlMonth` I need as default value : `January`;
3. in DDL `ddlYear` I need as default value : `0001`;

Using this code I don't have error but :

1. in DDL `ddlday` I have as default value : `01`;
2. in DDL `ddlMonth` I have as default value : `january`;
3. in DDL `ddlYear` I have as default value : `2019`;

[image]

[image]

Please can you help me ?

My code below.

**code-behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {           
            DateTime dateofBirth = DateTime.MinValue;

            ddlMonth.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(a => new
            {
                MonthName = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(a),
                MonthNumber = a
            });

            ddlMonth.DataBind();

            ddlYear.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 99, 100).Reverse();
            ddlYear.DataBind();

            ddlday.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Day.ToString();
            ddlMonth.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Month.ToString();
            ddlYear.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Year.ToString();

            ddlday.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)));
            ddlday.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void ddlMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlday.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)));
        ddlday.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Markup**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="sc" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlDay" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlday" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMonth" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlMonth" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="MonthName"
                                    DataValueField="MonthNumber" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMonth_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean like this: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-Day-Month-and-Year-Date-from-DropDownList-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for reply, but I know your suggestion page and but if try I have error...

Comment: Calling the datetime constructor automatically sets to 1/1/1.  new DateTime()

Comment: @jdweng do you mean this? `DateTime dateofBirth = new DateTime(1,1,1);` not change

Comment: I said : DateTime date = new DateTime();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but your ddlYear doesn't have value 1, only years in the range from 1920 to 2019.
Did you mean to include min year in the range?

```
    ddlYear.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 99, 100).Reverse().Append(1);
```

Comment: Yes Sir, I need include  min year in the range equals to `0001` and add interval `2019-2030`. When the values selected in DDL are `01/January/0001` means that a date is not available for recorded in the database

Comment: If you need exact "0001", then you need to populate ddlYear with string values, :        'ddlYear.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 99, 100).Reverse().Select(x => x.ToString()).Append("0001")'